# enable FTP in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, php4

I need to move some files to FTP using PHP4. I tried with ftp_connect(). When I run the PHP page with this method, I got this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ftp_connect()
```

After google, I found that, FTP should be enabled while installation of PHP. Now how can I enable FTP in my PHP4.?

(`phpinfo()` doesnt show anything about FTP. I did these things in SERVER. But in my local everything works fine. phpinfo() shows FTP Enabled.)

Comment: are you working with a webhost or a localserver?

Comment: Then your webserver doesn't support `ftp_` functions. You need to get in contact with your hoster

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kees Sonnema. I am working on both. I test locally. If success, I move those changes to Server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kingkero. I have access to php.ini which is in server. Do I need to change anything in php.ini.?

Comment: Which OS are you running for your local tests?

Comment: PHP **4**? For the love of the world, why?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aeronth. Windows 7

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon. PHP4 is client requirement